# Diferencia entre public, y no tener modificador de acceso en una variable TypeScript

Tags: typescript

Tengo los siguientes ejemplos:

**Sin public;**

```
 export class Persona {
   name: string;
   lastName: string;
   dni: string;
}
```

**Con public;**

```
 export class Persona {
   public name: string;
   public lastName: string;
   public dni: string;
}
```

Si dejo el atributo sin el modificador de acceso queda por defecto publico?
Posiblemente sea algo básico pero no se cual seria la definición correcta (Quiero que los atributos sean públicos para acceder a ellos desde el html en angular 5).

Comment: Cualquier miembro de clase es public por defecto: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

En Typescript hay 3 modificadores de acceso: public, private y protected ([Ver referencia](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), en inglés, para más detalles)

- `public`: Es el modificador **por defecto**. Esto es así porque Javascript no tiene estos modificadores y todo es público, así que por consistencia es normal que sea el valor por defecto.
- `private`: Los elementos (atributos y métodos) sólo son visibles dentro de la clase.
- `protected`: Los elementos sólo son visibles dentro de la clase y en las clases que hereden directamente de ésta.

Answer (score 4):

Segun la [documetacion](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html), en el subtitulo **Public, private, and protected modifiers**:

> En TypeScript, cada miembro es público por defecto.

Por lo que no hay diferencia entre ambos.